# ruby on rails string concationation like the php (.=)

Tags: php, ruby

im from php,
in php i overly use `.=` so, how do it in ruby?

Comment: There is no `=.` operator in PHP, only `.=`.

Comment: I'm sure there is lots of ways to produce the equivalent of PHP's "Parse error: syntax error" you'd get for using `=.`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [String concatenation and Ruby](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/377768/string-concatenation-and-ruby)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[String concatentation](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/String_concatenation) is done with `+` in Ruby:

```
$ irb
irb(main):001:0> "hello" + " " + "world"
=> "hello world"
irb(main):002:0> foo = "hello "
=> "hello "
irb(main):003:0> foo += "world"
=> "hello world"
```

@AboutRuby also mentions the `<<` operator:

```
irb(main):001:0> s = "hello"
=> "hello"
irb(main):002:0> s << " world"
=> "hello world"
irb(main):003:0> s
=> "hello world"
```

While his point that `+` creates a new string and `<<` modifies a string might seem like a small point, it matters a lot when you might have multiple references to your string object, or if your strings grow to be huge via repeated appending:

```
irb(main):004:0> my_list = [s, s]
=> ["hello world", "hello world"]
irb(main):005:0> s << "; goodbye, world"
=> "hello world; goodbye, world"
irb(main):006:0> my_list
=> ["hello world; goodbye, world", "hello world; goodbye, world"]
irb(main):007:0> t = "hello, world"
=> "hello, world"
irb(main):008:0> my_list = [t, t]
=> ["hello, world", "hello, world"]
irb(main):009:0> t += "; goodbye, world"
=> "hello, world; goodbye, world"
irb(main):010:0> my_list
=> ["hello, world", "hello, world"]
```

@AboutRuby mentioned he could think of *three* mechanisms for string concatenation; that reminded me of another mechanism, which is more appropriate when you've got an array of strings that you wish to join together:

```
irb(main):015:0> books = ["war and peace", "crime and punishment", "brothers karamozov"]
=> ["war and peace", "crime and punishment", "brothers karamozov"]
irb(main):016:0> books.join("; ")
=> "war and peace; crime and punishment; brothers karamozov"
```

The `.join()` method can save you from writing some awful loops. :)

Comment: The `<<` operator is usually preferred to `+=`.  The `+=` creates another String object, `<<` appends to the string without creating another object.

Comment: @AboutRuby, good point; examples added. I suggest adding an answer here too, so it can be upvoted. :)

Answer (score 2):

Use `+=`. or `.concat("string to add")`

Answer (score 1):

Is that for string concatenation? You use `+=` in ruby to concat string.