# Combining two string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, string

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [String concatenation and Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/377768/string-concatenation-and-ruby)

I would like to combine two string in rails. My database is Postgre and I want the string first_name and last_name to become one string called full_name.

How can I best achieve this? 
Thx

Comment: Can you be a little more specific? Do you just want a `full_name` method on your model? Do you want to combine the two columns in the database and end up with just a `full_name` column instead of the `first_name` and `last_name` columns that you currently have?

Answer (score 7):

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  def full_name
    "#{first_name} #{last_name}"
  end
end
```

Comment: hei, yea thats it. thx.it worked by just adding this code into my model.