# For rails app, how to show multiple flash[:notice] in html?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

This is what I wrote in a controller file, but only 1 notice (the last one) would appear.

```
flash[:notice] ="a: " + aa.to_s
flash[:notice] ="b: " + bb.to_s
flash[:notice] ="c: " + cc.to_s
```

I want to show all of the three notice together (at one time), is there anyway to achieve this?

in my html:

```
<% if notice %>
  <p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>
<% end %>
```

Comment: You can also use plain old String concatenation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/377768/string-concatenation-and-ruby

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could try like this

```
flash[:notice] = ["a: " + aa.to_s]
flash[:notice] << "b: " + bb.to_s
flash[:notice] << "c: " + cc.to_s
```

And then in your views, output it as

```
<%= flash[:notice].join("<br>") %>
```

or whatever you want in your view

Comment: @Niall and me has given answer at same time..i think only few seconds difference....:)

Comment: Thank you very much. It works, but it seems that the "<br>" works not as a new line, but a string in html... But it is ok, I changed it to /// so the result looks nice!

Comment: you could use .html_safe to output it properly

Comment: Yes @Niall is right.....you could use html_safe and this way, you can return HTML Safe strings

Comment: Oh, there is one more question, I found that all of the other notice does not work (error occurs). For example, "xxx was successfully removed" does not work. 

error: undefined method `join' for "Your food list is currently empty":String

Answer (score 4):

You can do this:

```
 flash[:notice] = ["a: " + aa.to_s]
 flash[:notice] << "b: " + bb.to_s
 flash[:notice] << "c: " + cc.to_s
```

And then:

```
 <% if notice %>
     <p id="notice"><%= notice.join("<br>").html_safe %></p>
 <% end %>
```

This is essentially because flash[:notice] can be any kind of object, so we can make it an array to work with multiple notices.

Answer (score 2):

Another way is to write helper methods like this

```
def flash_message(type, msg)
  flash[type] ||= []
  flash[type] << msg
end

def multiple_flash
  arr = []
  flash.each do |type, messages|
    messages.each do |m|
      arr << render(:partial => 'partials/flash', :locals => {:type => type, :message => m}) unless m.blank?
    end
  end
  arr.join('<br/>')
end
```

And in your controller do like this

```
flash_message :notice, 'msg1'
flash_message :notice, 'msg2'
flash_message :notice, 'msg3'
```

And in your view,you can just add like this

```
<%= multiple_flash %>
```

Comment: Thank you, where should I input the two methods? in model folder? or helper folder? I am new to rails, so excuse me..

Comment: The methods goes to `helper` and `flash_message :notice, 'msg1'` stuff goes to your `controller` and the last line to your `view`.

Comment: For all those who also want to use `flash.now`:  You will need to add in the line `flash.now[type.to_sym] ||= []`.  This must go before `flash[type] ||= []`.