# Chaining in rails (ERB) files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, syntax, erb

What is rubys (ERB) equivalent of the following PHP code?

```
<?php echo $first_variable . " " . $second_variable ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this:
`<%= first_variable_value + " " + second_variable_value %>`

However, if variables store `Fixnum` instead of `String` then the following error occurs
`TypeError: String can't be coerced into Fixnum`.

Therefore the best approach would be
`<%= "#{first_variable} #{last_variable}" %>`

Interpolation implecitly converts the `Fixnum` into `String` and problem solved.

Comment: I think you meant `<%= first_variable_value + " " + second_variable_value %>`. The way you have it, it will just print the words `first_variable_value` and `second_variable_value`

Comment: in case `first_variable` is a complex object (e.g. Rails model instance), this would end with `undefined method + for Model:0x0000000dd7ef30`

Answer (score 3):

```
<%= "#{first_variable} #{second_variable}" %>
```

Note that variables gonna be transformed to string representation (which could produce some unexpected outputs like "Photo:0x0000000dc9f5b0"). More on various ways to concatenate strings here: [String concatenation in Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/377768/string-concatenation-in-ruby)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `"` to print a variable; you can do so without `"`.

```
<%= first_variable %>
```

This is equivalent of following PHP code:

```
<?php echo $first_variable ?>
```

So in order to do what you have asked in your question, the following code is suitable:

```
<%= first_variable + " " + last_variable %>
```

You don't need to surround your variables with `"`. And `+` operator here does the job for concatenation.

And in case, if you are not sure that variables are actually string object, the you can use either of the following techniques:

```
<%= first_variable.to_s + " " + last_variable.to_s %>
<%= "#{first_variable} #{last_variable}" %>
```

Comment: not really true. in case `first_variable` is a complex object (e.g. Rails model instance), this would end with `undefined method + for Model:0x0000000dd7ef30`

Comment: I've assumed them to be strings. Let me edit the answer.