# Using gsub to add to a phone number

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, gsub

I am trying to save a client’s phone number to the DB and make it E.164 compliant so we can send them an SMS. We were using a gem to do this, but the powers that be decided they don’t want to do it that way anymore. I am trying to accomplish this using a before_validation and a model method. I have pasted them below, but can’t seem to figure out how to add a +1 that is required. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

listing_collection.rb

```
before_validation :format_phone

def format_phone
  self.client_phone = client_phone.gsub(/\D/, '')
end
```

Comment: The string `"+1"+...`...? What am I missing here?

Comment: You are missing the fact that I was likely trying to overcomplicate things. Haha.

Comment: Happens to the best of us. You may want to make a phone number "canonicizer" concern (module) that handles all sorts of broken and garbage data, as that way you can write tests for that method specifically.

Comment: `phone_number.prepend "+1"` ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [String concatenation in Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/377768/string-concatenation-in-ruby)